# Process all audio streams in MKV using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to do dynamic audio normalization in MKV file containing audio streams in two languages

```
ffmpeg -i "Source.mkv" -vcodec copy -af "dynaudnorm=f=50:p=0.9" "Target.mkv"
```

After this command the result contains only the first audio stream.

How to make FFMPEG to keep video as it is and process all the audio streams, no matter how many they are?

**Update**

`-map 0` ends with an error "Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1".

`-map 0:a` ends with an error "Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0."

`-map 0:2` causes FFMPEG to leave only one stream in target file, and this stream is the second audio. (and I need an universal command that is able to process ALL the streams without changing anything in command line)

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved? If so, please edit your question and remove the "Update" section or clarify that these errors were not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-map` flag to select specific streams as described [here.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

If you want to select all streams· add `-map 0`
If you want to select all audio streams, add `-map 0:a`

In your case that would be:
`ffmpeg -i "Source.mkv" -map 0:a -vcodec copy -af "dynaudnorm=f=50:p=0.9" "Target.mkv"`

Comment: `-map 0` ends with an error "Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1". `-map 0:a` ends with an error "Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0."

Comment: @Paul `-map 0` is the answer to your question. It looks like the error message is now a fully different problem , which must be adressed by a new question

Comment: @Paul That is a well documented error. Easy to find a solution: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686244/ffmpeg-too-many-packets-buffered-for-output-stream-01), [2](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6375)